# How to use LogonUser CreateProcessAsUser when only a PIN is defined?

Tags: delphi, windows-11, createprocessasuser, windows-hello

In our application we manage a user database in which we have the option to log in to our app by verifying username and password with the local installation. By now we actually used `LogonUser` for that purpose.

So... Now with Windows 11 the default option is to have either biometric login or a PIN which is obviously incompatible with `LogonUser` (heck, on my PC I don't have a local password nor have I found the possibility to create one in the dialogs).

Now, what is the route to take from here? I couldn't figure what's the way to go (note: it's a similar problem to `CreateProcessAsUser`) - I always find links to Windows Hello/Windows credential provider interfaces, but as far as I can see these are used to be a provider yourself...

Comment: So you have multiple users with the same windows login using your app?

Comment: Yes indeed... and also the other way round - multiple win users identify as one user in our system.